Understanding one time non consumed purchases in Android In App Billing 7 implementation
am trying to upgrade my in app billing with version 7.0.0.
In the following link: in app billing Android integration
I see the following which is confusing:
The following example shows how to fetch for a user's subscription purchases. Note that queryPurchasesAsync() returns only active subscriptions and non-consumed one-time purchases.
What do they mean by non-consumed one-time purchase?
can it be:
Say a magical weapon in a game that be bought over and over again, as long as it has been consumed.
Can it also be the solution to a math problem in a calculator app that can be bought over and over again, as long as it has been consumed.
Or, is it a strict one timer purchase that can never be bought again within the app?
Thanks for the clarification.
